# Unable to analyse Javascript file with SonarQube

Tags: javascript, sonarqube, sonarqube-msbuild-runner

When trying to do analysis of a project using the javascript 2.9 plugin (using SonarQube 5.2 and the MSBuild runner) I am getting the error on a file

> ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution [error]Caused by:
>   org.sonar.squidbridge.api.AnalysisException: Unable to analyse file:
>   C:/Builds/source/_work/thefile.js

I have tried uninstalling the javascript plugin, but that just moved the issues to the failure being on a CSS file, as in [CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33551357/5-2-upgrade-illegalargumentexception-unable-to-highlight-file) reported issue

Anyone got a solution that does not involve unloading the javascript and css plugins?

Comment: Do you have more information in the logs of the analysis?

Comment: Yes I have the failing logs from the build process. How is it best to get them to you?

Comment: You should be able to see the log file from our MSBuild runner task here https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=8A3B7BA98D7F565E!9026&authkey=!AFwuwaZffLYVsa0&ithint=file%2ctxt

Comment: You can see most of the analysis is OK then it failed to read some standard umbraco .js files. If I disable javascript and css plugins the .NET analysis completes OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logs contain some stacktraces which contain useful information. The errors you get come from the SonarQube Web plugin, not the JavaScript plugin. I created the following ticket to track this issue: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARWEB-43

**Edit**:
This bug in the SonarQube Web plugin prevents the analysis from completing. The Web plugin is automatically called in the analysis because it's supposed to analyse all files which name ends with ".html".

Possible workarounds:

- Disable the plugin for the analysis with the following setting: `sonar.excludePlugins=web`
- Exclude html files from the analysis

See http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters and http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild+Configuration

Comment: Thanks for that, but how does that explain why I cannot complete analysis with the CSS and JavaScript plugins, but can if they are removed?